# Vue.js merge data without a re-render?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `search` component that gets its data in the form as a prop of PHP `json_encoded` data:

```
<search :data="<?= json_encode($jsonHotels) ?>"></search>
```

This way it receives the first 25 movies straight away when the page renders.

After this I make an ajax request to fetch the rest of the result if there are more than 25 movies.

The problem is that when I override the data with the data from the AJAX call, the component re-renders.

Previously to combat this I performed an ajax request with an offset of 25 to skip the first 25 movies and only give me the extra results. Pushing this onto the array didn't cause a re-render and this worked perfectly.

That was perfect, until I got to thinking:

> What about people who start or refresh the page while they are on page number 2-3-4-5-etc.

I now have to not only mess with my offset, but I also have to possibly prepend data to my array and well as possibly append data with a push.

Is there a way to merge data without causing a re-render? I am wondering if anyone else has every run into the problem.

Simply fetching all results with an AJAX request takes too long and obviously also causes a re-render. Not fetching initial backend data would mean people would be starting at a blank page or a spinner for 2-3 seconds.

**Edit:**

Ended up with this:

```
mergeData(state) {
    // Smart merge ajaxData and hotels.
    const offSet = state.currentPage * state.itemsPerPage;

    const start = state.ajaxData.slice(0, offSet - state.itemsPerPage);
    const end = state.ajaxData.slice(offSet);

    state.data.unshift(...start);
    state.data.push(...end);
},
```

Pretty much slice my array in 2 and remove the `currentPage` section. By using `unshift` and `push` I prevent a re-render from happening.

Comment: Your data prop is not bound to a variable, so how are you overriding the data? From *within* the search component or externally?

Comment: What happens that makes a re-render of the exact same data a problem?

Comment: I have a transition group in Vue which slides in my v-for items whenever they are rendered. Similar to this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions So when my ajax content is loaded they slide in a second time which is kind of confusing for a user even if it is the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that your viewmodel is a model of your view. Here, you're not modeling your application, you're just trying to plug your data in.

If you want to display a page of results at a time, have some kind of model for a page of results. When you fetch your data, put it into the appropriate model-pages. Since you're only displaying one page at a time, populating other pages will not cause a re-render.

Comment: This requires me to have knowledge on exactly which pages to update though. I guess there will be no way around this. Let's say a user starts on page 3 I need to only push pages 1,2 and pages after 3. Currently I already have paginated results exactly like you mention.

Comment: When you're populating the pages, you iterate through them all and skip the current page. Although replacing the current page data with an exact duplicate shouldn't cause an actual re-render.